# Is there a function to apply colors to masked corners of a view or button?

Tags: ios, cornerradius

I need to know is there any function to fill the masked corners. I have tried CAShapelayer still, it is overlapping with the outside view. So, I need to fill it perfectly without showing the background color.

The below image shows the corners are occupied with pink color. But I need those colors to match with white.

[image: cornerradius_image]

Comment: I don't know if there is any function to do that, but you can add a new view between the blue one and the pink, with a white background color to do the trick.

Comment: For every corner? How do we get the coordinates for that curvature?

Comment: If you are using auto layout, set the constraints to 0. If programmatically you can add a view and make the frames equal.

Comment: Do you want the blue rounded-corners-rect to be transparent?

Comment: Yeah. Actually, the background view of the blue color is Pink. But I need those masked corners of blue one to be white.  The white view is the overlay.

Comment: @kumaraprasad7 - sorry, that's still not clear what you want... Do you want a **blue** rect with rounded corners, so the white background shows instead of the pink corners? Do you want a **pink** rect with a clear center, so the white background shows through the center? Do you want a **white** rect with a **blue** rounded-corners rect inside? Either show an image of what you ***want***, or, take a look at this and see if A, B or C is what you want: https://imgur.com/a/RhMjIkn

Comment: I need the view same as C.

Comment: @kumaraprasad7 - if you want "C" (pink corners in your image will be clear / transparent), simply set the background color of the subView to blue, and set `theSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 24.0` (or whatever radius value you want).

Comment: Actually the pink corners are not the background color of the subView. It is the super view. There are three Views, pink, white and blue. White is on the top. I have cropped the white-colored exactly to the blue one dimensions.  The blue one is in between pink and white. So, the corner colors of the blue one depend on the super view(Pink).

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the corner radius

```
 view.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
 view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: I need to color only the masked corners.

Comment: if you apply corner radius to lower view now masked corner will be shown

Comment: I need to turn the pink color which is surrounded on blue color to be white.